# Debian Testing install USB menu does not respond to keyboard

Tags: installation, keyboard, debian, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to install Debian Testing onto my Acer Aspire One ZG5 using the testing versions of boot.img and debian-testing-i386-CD-1.iso. I previously installed (two days ago) the latest release of stable, and the boot.img/CD1 from that worked fine, and installed seamlessly. With testing though, the menu does not respond to the keyboard as soon as the menu appears to select Install/Graphical install/Help, etc. I have also tried to boot with an external (USB) keyboard, which again, works fine with the stable version of boot.img/CD1, but not testing.

I did some searching and couldn't find anything that looked similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Cherry keyboard you seem to suffer from [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=584973).